# Quartz Scheduler job runs continuously after trigger

Tags: quartz-scheduler, mirth

I am using a product called Mirth to reach out to an SFTP server and download a handful of files on a weekly basis. The product has a cron feature, where it allows you to use a cron expression to do configure this function.

The cron expression I am using:

```
0 45 13 ? * MON *
```

NOTE: This is not typical Linux-based cron. It's a cron expression spec used by Java for scheduling things even down to the second (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm).

Is supposed to reach out at 1:45 PM every Monday and pull down files. But when it reaches out it does so continuously for 20 minutes or so, downloading the same files a few hundred times instead of just once.

Is there vagueness in this expression? It seems like it should only call once. I did just notice that there appears to be a space at the very beginning of the expression, not sure how that would make the thing run for 20 minutes again and again, though.

Comment: You may want to remove the linux tag and add quartz-scheduler instead to try to get this reopened. I don't see why it wouldn't be working. Maybe try changing your MON to a 2 and dropping the * for the year as it's optional. This is the actual api doc https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/CronExpression.html

Comment: If you're question gets reopened we can check your schedule using https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html . You should also look in Mirth Connect, it should tell you the next execution time in the source configuration tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could ease your crontab scheduling with crontab generators, like ie. this website:

[www.crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/)
or
[www.crontab-generator.org](https://crontab-generator.org/)

(These are first two Google results)

From what you described, it looks like invalid syntax for crontab.

**EDITED:**
1:45 PM every Monday would be:

```
45 13 * * 1
```

Comment: I actually did use a similar site to generate this

Comment: Then this is wrong, because crontab have 5 different "slots" for representing time (which are "*" ), in your syntax there would be 7, including signs like "?" which are non existing in crontab

Comment: Went and looked at the cron spec, you are right, this is a different spec, it is one that is utilized by Java and allows for scheduling by seconds.  Thanks for your input, I'll update my question to call that out.